# Convert timezone difference to an integer value

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the offset in hours between two timezones.

The `hour_offset` variable is of type set and I'm looking to be able to use the value for other calculations, so in the below example the calculation should read 9 hours.

```
<class 'set'>
{8.0}
      print(1 + hour_offset)
          ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'set'
```

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt = datetime.now()
tz0, tz1 = "America/Los_Angeles", "Europe/London"

utcoff0, utcoff1 = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo(tz0)).utcoffset(), dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo(tz1)).utcoffset()

print(f"hours offset between {tz0} -> {tz1} timezones: {(utcoff1-utcoff0).total_seconds()/3600}")

hour_offset = ({(utcoff1-utcoff0).total_seconds()/3600})

print(type(hour_offset))
print(hour_offset)

print(1 + hour_offset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hour_offset` is a set because that's how it's being defined in the code. [`{...}` defines a set literal](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
hour_offset = ({(utcoff1-utcoff0).total_seconds()/3600})
#              ^----------this defines a set----------^
```

Get rid of the curly braces (and you can also lose the outermost parentheses):

```
hour_offset = (utcoff1 - utcoff0).total_seconds() / 3600
```

---

Side note: Not all time zone offsets will be integers. For example, [Newfoundland](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/nst).